# Addition of oxygen molecule to given aromatic compound

Tags: organic-chemistry

I did figure out that the hydrogen atom is reactive as it has three electron donating groups attached to it, I know it reacts. But the answer given is that 6 different compounds can be formed (minor and major; including stereoisomers). But I need some help figuring them out.
[image: problem figure]

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumene_process for mechanism. I did not look at it too closely, but my intuition is that one of the three aryl groups can migrate, and each product has two enantiomers, so $3\times 2 = 6$ products in total.

Comment: Ahhh, I see what you mean. Yep, that's most probably the solution. I think i understand now. Thank you so much, i appreciate your help. But just to add something to the question, what would be the major product? does it have anything to do with the groups attached to the benzene rings and their +R effect? @orthocresol

Answer (score -2):

The three hydrogen bond at -OCH3 would be reactive and 
-CH3 at attached directly to ring would react so 6 products possible.

Comment: Well, what is the product?